# Can QT open a Linux terminal and then write into it?

Tags: linux, qt, terminal

I can open a terminal by doing this from my QT code:

QProcess process;

process.start("xterm");
process.waitForFinished(-1);

But then I can't figure out how to write commands to it?

I need to do that because I want my app to ssh an equipment and then write commands once logged in and see the output.

I'm open to other solutions too!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

QProcess has a write command, but you don't want to be calling waitForFinished.

```
QProcess proc;
proc.start("xterm");
proc.waitForStarted();
proc.write(someData, dataSize);
```

If you want response from the terminal, connect a slot to the readyRead() signal

```
// Qt 5 syntax 
connect(proc &QProcess::readyRead, this, &MyClass::readData());
```

Then call one of the read functions, such as readAll() from your readData slot function.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer.
I tried what you suggested but I get this error running your code:

QProcess: Destroyed while process is still running.

Comment: You need to dynamically allocate the process (QProcess* proc = new QProcess) and delete it at the appropriate time, perhaps by linking to the finished() signal and calling deleteLater(). I allocated it on the stack, following the example code in your question.

Comment: thanks it fixed that error. But then, for example proc->write("pwd") will not write in the terminal.

Comment: Check for any errors in the process, connecting a slot to the error signal. Also, I've not tried this, but if you write "pwd", perhaps you need to send a return byte too? If that still doesn't work, I recommend starting a new SO question.

Comment: Tried both your advice, without success... thank you though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Are you waiting to receive login data before writing? If you're connecting to an ssh session, I think you should be doing that.